# macOS bird application files showing in security panel?

Tags: security, macos-big-sur

MacOS’ bird process creates a cache folder containing a lot of files with no meaningful names, ok. Gotten used to it.

Recently I noticed that some of these files being applications had been entered into security access system panel, claiming access to mic, camera, files etc.
I’ve never seen something like this before and removed their rights, obviously without consequences to my iMac’s behavior.
Is this a normal behavior? Or should I be worried?